# how to get all base (parent or root) categories from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, radix

I have this categories:

level_1

-->> level_1.1

-->> level_1.2

level_2

-->> level_2.1

----->>level_2.1.1

level_3

level_4

-->>level_4.1

I need base levels (level1, level2, level3, level4) with id and title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$root_categories = get_categories( 
    array(
        'parent' => 0,
    ) 
);
$newResult = array();
foreach($root_categories as $key => $value)
{
    $newResult[] = array(
        "id" => $value->term_id,
        "name" => $value->name
    );
}
var_dump($newResult);
```